# Duplicate Rows on SQL Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I do a left join on a table it duplicates the results from the left table when more values are found in the right table.
How can I only return the distinct values from the left even when there are multiple values on the right table.
(return only the one movie even when there are multiple images on the right table)

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Movie AS M
    LEFT JOIN MovieImage AS MI WITH (
        NOLOCK
) ON M.TheMovieDbId = MI.TheMovieDbId
WHERE
    MI.ImageType = 'Poster'
    AND MI.ImageSize = 'Thumb'
    OR MI.ImageType IS NULL
```

Comment: You have do decide *which* `MovieImage` you want and describe it exactly. You might find a criteria to get a 1-1 matching. If don't, you may have to join with an aggregated result...

Comment: What are you using? mysql, mssql, oracel

Comment: That depends. You will have to define which of the available images it should take (and 'just pick one' is not a valid answer here). Depending on the answer you'll end up most likely with a subselect and something like a min() or a max() or even a group by

Comment: Thanks Eddy. Sorry Im new to sql. How do I just "pick one" when there are multiple images?

Comment: Write what do you want to select from Movies and What you want from MovieImages

Comment: If there are multiple images which one to take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you wouldn't use a "right table" if you don't want results from it.

```
SELECT 
     *
FROM 
    Movie AS M
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT *
      FROM
          MovieImage AS MI
      WHERE  
          M.TheMovieDbId = MI.TheMovieDbId
          AND
          MI.ImageType = 'Poster'
          AND 
          MI.ImageSize = 'Thumb')
```

To have rows where no rows match too (as per your query), use this

```
SELECT 
     *
FROM 
    Movie AS M
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT *
      FROM
          MovieImage AS MI
      WHERE  
          M.TheMovieDbId = MI.TheMovieDbId
          AND
          MI.ImageType = 'Poster'
          AND 
          MI.ImageSize = 'Thumb')
UNION
SELECT * FROM Movie
```

Otherwise, you are saying "give me an arbitrary row from  MovieImage" which I never understand...

Other notes:

- don't use NOLOCK all the time
- qualify your table names with schema name (typically dbo)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to pick one, why not just do a `group by`, and select `min()` or `max()`? Depending if you want to get all movies regardless if they have a image or not, use the `left join`. If you only want the movies that have images, use `inner join`. If you only want the movies that have a specific number of images, use the `having` clause.

Simplified example:

```
Select M.Name, isnull(max(MI.ImageName), 'No Image')
From Movie M
Left Join MovieImage MI
On M.TheMovieDbId = MI.TheMovieDbId
Group By M.Name
```